# Order of Validation When Using Annotations and Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've noticed that while creating a custom validation attribute, my validation only fires after native MVC data annotations fire. Is there any way it could fire "at the same time"?

To show what I mean, pretend I have this form:

```
FirstName: <FirstName Textbox>
LastName: <LastName TextBox>
Zip: <Zip TextBox>
```

So I have a [Required] annotation for all 3, but in addition, for the Zip property, I have a custom attribute. If the user DOESN'T enter a firstname or lastname, but enters an invalid Zip (which my attribute should validate this), there should be an error message on all three - but there isn't. There's only an error on firstName and lastName.

This is the code:

Person.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

// My validator
using MvcApplication3.Extensions.Validation;

namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
  public class Person
  {
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Field required!")]
    public string firstName{get;set;}

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Field required!")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }    

    [Zip(ErrorMessage="You gotta put in a valid zip code")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Field required!")]
    public string zipCode { get; set; }    
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form, Person person)
{
  return View(person);
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.Person
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Person";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";       

}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>
  Testing Form: @Model.firstName
</h2>
<hr />

@{Html.EnableClientValidation();}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstName) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.firstName) 
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.firstName)

  <br /><br />
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastName) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.lastName) 
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.lastName)

  <br /><br />
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.zipCode) 
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.zipCode) 
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.zipCode)    

  <br /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Zip Validator (Zip.cs):

```
  public class ZipAttribute : ValidationAttribute
  {
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
      bool foundMatch = false;
      try
      {
        foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(value.ToString(), "\\A\\b[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?\\b\\z");
      }
      catch (ArgumentException ex)
      {
        // Syntax error in the regular expression
      }
      return foundMatch;
    }
  }
```

Also, I know I can do this with Regexp data annotation, but I'm looking to roll my own custom validators in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a Javascript version of your validation that will run client-side (or disable client-side validation, but that's a bit naff).

There's a sample of building custom validation for email addresses here:

http://thepursuitofalife.com/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-javascript-validation-with-custom-validators/

This shows the C# code (which includes setting the javascript function name that will do the client-side validation) as well as the javascript "validemail" routine.

```
public class ValidEmailAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    // ...

    public IEnumerable GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName),
            ValidationType = "validemail"
        };
    }
}
```

And the JS:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("validemail", function (value, element, param) {
        var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
        return emailPattern.test(value);
    });
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("validemail");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a better solution than disabling unobtrusive client validation.

Since you're only matching a regular expression, you might try doing this instead (will work with javascript validation):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ZipAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public ZipAttribute() : base("\\A\\b[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?\\b\\z")
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Invalid ZIP code.";
    }
}
```

and in Global.asax:

```
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(ZipAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

What's nice about doing it this way, you can specify your own default Error Messages!

Weird enough, some of the validation attributes (StringLength, Range, RegularExpression) still use AttributeAdapters, while other attributes such as the CompareAttribute uses the IClientValidatable.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeap, that's sort of what I'm looking for, but I'd like to use custom C# logic to validate, not a regular expression. 

Rather than inheriting from RegularExpressionAttribute, can I inherit from some class where I can put in my own validation logic code?

Comment: You still need to write client-side Javascript, if you're going to use custom code. There is no automatic conversion of C# code into Javascript code. You have to do that work yourself.

Comment: The 'weirdness' of why some attributes use IClientValidatable and some don't is because the ones that ship with the .NET framework (Required and friends), they have no knowledge of MVC. The IClientValidatable interface is an MVC interface, not a .NET interface. The CompareAttribute is shipped with MVC, so it's aware of (and can implement) IClientValidatable.

Comment: Sorry if I'm a little late to the game here. Thanks for all the responses - they all make perfect sense. It does seem a bit painful, though to me, shoe-horning the client-side validation. Since it seems easier to just plug in the jQuery validation code in there, independently of the C# code - is there any advantage to doing so? That is, why would I want to inherit from IClientValidatable and add additional C# logic, where I STILL have to implement the validation logic in JavaScript? Doesn't seem to be any benefit.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is happening is because you have unobtrusive client side validation enabled, and your custom validation attribute doesn't implement `IClientValidatable`.  It would need to implement this to allow the rendering of `data-*` attributes which are needed as part of the client validation process.  You would also need to provide a client side regex validation routine that mirrors you server side validation.

If you want to go the easy route, disable client side validation and unobtrusive javascript in web.config like so:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"/> 
</appSettings>
```

Your page should then behave how you would expect, but all your validation will now occur on the server.  If you want to give the unobtrusive client side validation a whirl, then these links should helpful.

- [Unobtrusive Client Validation in
  ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)
- [Unobtrusive custom
  validator for MVC3](http://johnmj.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/unobtrusive-custom-validator-for-mvc3/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So I pretty much have to write equivalent JavaScript code that matches my validator?

Comment: Sadly you do - see the link in my answer below. You could possible do this with Script#, but there's nothingbuilt-in to convert your C# to Javascript (but that is what Script# is intended to do :-))